# Bash script to move first N files with specific name

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to move only 100 files with a specific extensions (from the current directory to the parent directory), but the following attempt of mine does not work

```
for file in $(ls -U | grep *.txt | tail -100)
do
    mv $file ../
done
```

Can you point me to the correct approach?

Comment: `grep *.txt` is not correct, since the shell expands the wildcard. Use `ls *.txt`

Comment: @Barmar, parsing `ls`' output is [notoriously a pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). The user should rely on `find`.

Comment: @Enrico I know, although any solution that pipes to `tail -100` is going to run into similar pitfalls.

Comment: @Barmar, sure, but I'm not sure piping into tail is the only way to go. Maybe it is, let's see. Besides, the OP hasn't explained what does _100 files_ mean. The first 100 when sorted alphabetically? The 100 biggest files? Who knows...

Comment: `-U` disables sorting, so it seems to mean the last 100 in whatever order they happen to be stored in the directory.

Comment: @Shneor : I don't know why you want to use grep (except if you one day want to extend your solution to a more complicated pattern, which would need a regex), but if you use _grep_, the pattern would be `grep '[.]txt$'`, and this of course assumes that your filenames don't have embedded newline characters.

Comment: Can I ask you about the specifics of `ls -U`? It is a very unusual command and seems to introduce an uncontrollable input (See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13451/273492) for some details)

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't quote `*.txt`, the shell expanded it to all the filenames ending in `.txt`. So your command is something like:

```
ls -U | grep file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ... | tail -100
```

Since `grep` has filename arguments, it ignores its standard input. It outputs all the lines matching `file1.txt` in the remaining files. There's probably no matches, so nothing is piped to `tail -100`. And even if there were matches, the output would be the lines from the files, not filenames, so it wouldn't be useful for the `mv` command.

You can loop over the filenames directly, and use a counter variable to stop after 100 files.

```
counter=0
for file in *.txt
do
    if (( counter >= 100 ))
    then break
    fi

    mv "$file" ../
    ((counter++))
done
```

This avoids the pitfalls of parsing the output of `ls`.

Comment: `bash` expands a filename pattern by sorting the result alphanumeric. The OP wants to get the first 100 by directory order. Honestly, I don't know how we can get this in bash (without resorting to `ls`).

Comment: Honestly I can't think of any reason why he would really want to do it in directory order, as that has no relationship to anything meaningful. It would make more sense to do it in order of modification time.

Comment: But if not that, lexicographic order is probably just as good as anything else.

Comment: Neither do I, but observing that he explicitly used the `-U` flag in his command, I assume that he wants to have directory order.

Comment: @user1934428 Or maybe he just doesn't care about the order and is trying to improve performance by not sorting.

Comment: @user1934428 I believe we need to make the safe assumption that the OP just did a copy/paste from some other code. The `-U` only makes sense in the above context if the OP has full control on the directory order (i.e. he knows how to manipulate the file system and uses it to his benefit to store "other" additional information, whatever that might be). If this would be the case, I don't expect this question from the OP.

Comment: @user1934428

The order does not matter.
Just a copy and paste from multiple trials I did before posting this question.
Cheers!

Comment: @Shneor : Then please add this information to your question, instead of including it in a comment. BTW: If you want a _random_ selection, consider piping your file list through `shuf` before taking the `head` or `tail`. If you don't do this, the selection will be biased in that you tend to move files which are, i.e., early in sorting order, neglecting those which sort late, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the job:

```
ls -U *.txt | tail -100 | while read filename; do mv "$filename" ../; done
```

`while read filename` respect spaces in the filename.

Comment: You forgot the `-U` for the `ls` command. Also, I don't quite see in what respect this solution is better than the one the OP presented.

Comment: @user1934428 The one in the OP misuses `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the text file directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

for txt_file in ./*.txt; do
        ((c++==100)) && break
        mv "$txt_file" ../
done
```